# Why updating skiping a column after the others

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to import each column of a sheet into multiple choice. it works but I observed that it skipped some columns .Please help me, I don't know what went wrong.

```
  function updateFormFromData() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 //Get data, number of questions and options info
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numOfOptions = data.length-3;
  var numOfQs = data[0].length;

  //Get questions
  var questions = sh.getRange(2, 2, 1, numOfQs).getValues();

  //Get options and store in an array
  var allOptions = [];
  for (q=2;q<=numOfQs;q++){
  var options = sh.getRange(3, q, numOfOptions, 1).getValues();
  allOptions.push(options);
  }

  //Get existing form
  var form = FormApp.openById('1UHWkwjpssK-D2m8MUEXeSIzX4x3jLTzc-mts8kCExiI');
  var allItems = form.getItems();
  for (var k = 0; k < numOfQs-1;k++) {      
  var value = allItems[k];  
  //questions and options to form  
  for (qq=0;qq<numOfQs-1;qq++){
 switch (allItems[qq].getType()) {      
 case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
  var formQ = allItems[qq].asMultipleChoiceItem();

   formQ.setTitle(questions[0][qq]);
  formQ.setChoiceValues(allOptions[qq]);
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, or at least a screenshot, showing how the questions and options are structured in the sheet, so that this issue is clarified?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SqSjoV-izUNnjaSl9aJa9J8RsGfbpFbH3l77ze-XMbQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You are iterating through all items in your form, but you only want to modify the `MULTIPLE_CHOICE` items. If there are any in-between items that are not `MULTIPLE_CHOICE`, the corresponding question (identified by the counter `qq`) will be skipped.

#### Solution:

Retrieve `MULTIPLE_CHOICE` items instead of all items in the Form. You can do that by using [Form.getItems(itemType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getItems(ItemType)) instead of [Form.getItems()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getitems).

So, replace this:

```
var allItems = form.getItems();
```

With this:

```
var allItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
```

#### Note:

Make sure there are not more `questions` than `MULTIPLE_CHOICE` items. Otherwise `allItems[qq]` will be `undefined` for the later iterations.

Comment: thanks it works like charm. However what if I have other items other than MULTIPLE_CHOICE, how can I go about it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @FrankIgbekeleFanimo What do you mean? You mean what to do if there are other types of items for which you want to add choices/edit?